# Обработчики кнопок

Tags: java, javafx

Я работаю с базой данных. Оттуда я вывожу сколько необходимо создать кнопок. Динамически их создаю. Но мне необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку показывался месендж бокс с инфой. Для каждой кнопки разный текст.
Помогите это реализовать.

Comment: А где код ? Смотрите в сторону JavaFX Alert Dialog или создавайте свой.

Answer (score 0):

Подставьте под каждую кнопку активное действие

```
Button b = new Button();
b.setOnAction(e->infoBox(b));
```

Верните Pane который вам нужен.

```
 public static void infoBox(Button b){
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Test Info");

        alert.setHeaderText("Here:");

        alert.getDialogPane().setContent(nodeInformation(b));


        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    public static Pane nodeInformation(Button b){

        // По кнопке генерируем возвращаем нужный Pane
        // С информацией которая вам нужна.
        return new Pane(); // Удалить, для пояснения.
    }
```